# Is it a bad idea to monkey patch Object to have a more natural way for testing if an element is in an array?

Tags: ruby, class, object, monkeypatching

Bothered by that we could test in Ruby whether an array (or another Enumerable) contains a value with the `include?` method...

```ruby
puts %w(one two three four).include?("two")
# => true
puts %w(one two three four).include?("five")
# => false
```

... but not directly test whether a value is included in an array (semantically identical, but not part of the language)...

```ruby
puts "two".in?( %w(one two three four) )
puts "five".in?( %w(one two three four) )
```

I thought about monkey patching `Object` to have a handy `Object#in?` method, something similar to:

```ruby
class Object
  def in?(array)
    return false unless array.respond_to?(:include?)  # Or perhaps raise an error.
    return array.include?(self)
  end
end
```

With that method definition on `Object`, things like

```ruby
"two".in?( %w(one two three four) )
# => true
:nuts.in?( [:banana, :chocolate, :pie] )
# => false
```

work nicely, and are very close to a normal sentence expressing that test.

Frequently, I run into that `if element.in?(array)` is a subtly more natural expression than `if array.include?(element)`, especially if the array is included as a literal (instead of a variable reference).

Question (while neglecting the general opinion on monkey patching): is this example of monkey patching a smart thing to do? What are specific drawbacks for having an `Object#in?` method, again not going into the generic pros and cons of monkey patching objects (in Ruby)?

Comment: Oh, I just discover that Ruby on Rails does something similar, adding `#in?` to `Object`. So, I'm alone with this goal about striving for code to be close to a normal natural expression in English.

Comment: I would recommend as a minimum change calling the method `included_in?` this way there is a simple implication that the object being passed should implement include.

Comment: @engineersmnky, I understand, and I like the consequential implication ... but it's just not how I verbalize the statement. In my head, I think "is this value _in_ this array?" (and not "is this value _included in_ this array?") but YMMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the general arguments for/against monkey patching in Ruby, the code you describe is an example of a *convenience method* to help with your readability. Arguments against its inclusion also apply to the generic case as well, so there doesn't appear to be a specific drawback. Technically, this method is already included in the Ruby on Rails framework, so the authors shared your view in supporting it as a natural expression.

Comment: Accepting this answer, as it addresses (or at least: mentions) the point of a potential drawback of monkey patching, in the light of the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I would either require the appropriate Rails Active Support module ([core_ext/object/inclusion.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/inclusion.rb)) into your project, or if you are going to modify `Object` yourself, use the same source code as Rails' [Object#in?](https://api.rubyonrails.org/) method.

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/inclusion.rb, line 12
def in?(another_object)
  another_object.include?(self)
rescue NoMethodError
  raise ArgumentError.new("The parameter passed to #in? must respond to #include?")
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw that code snippet as well. At least using the same code (especially in handling an argument error - an object that doesn't respond to `include?`) conforms to a common-ish opinion.

Comment: Oh, for a non-web application in Ruby - yes, it happens - I'd not opt quickly for requiring Rails modules in my project. Then I'd favor to just monkey patch `Object` myself (but using the similar code, decreasing the chance of confusion).